# Unable to read local file in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I was using Pig (installed from Cloudera) in 'local mode' and not in MapReduce mode. The scripts worked fine on my laptop (Mac OS). But when I attempt to use Pig on AWS server, Pig fails to read or write to a file.

Here are the Pig commands:

```
$ pwd
/root/ert/test

$ pig -x local -l /tmp

grunt> pwd
file:/root/ert/test
grunt> ls
file:/root/ert/test/t.pig<r 1>  1697
file:/root/ert/test/test5.csv<r 1>  330
file:/root/ert/test/test5.pig<r 1>  120
file:/root/ert/test/test5.tsv<r 1>  293

grunt>  testdata    = load 'test5.tsv' as (name:chararray, lob:chararray, date:chararray);
```

The input data file (test5.tsv) is located in current directory and its content are:

```
John    WIRELESS    2014-01-01 00:30:15
Doe TELECOM 2014-02-02 00:30:15
NYC WIRELESS    2014-03-03 00:30:15
Chicago WIRELINE    2014-04-04 00:30:15
SanFrancisco    WIRELESS    2014-05-05 00:30:15
```

The Error I get is:

```
Input(s):
Failed to read data from "file:///root/ert/test/test5.tsv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp-1810274881/tmp1793050127"
```

I installed just Pig using `yum` ($ yum install pig) with cloudera's CDH5 repo. I read on the web that this could be due to read and write privileges of a 'staging' directory but have no idea which is the staging directory.

Pig was initially complaining about lack of HBase. After installing HBase those errors stopped but still unable to read the input file.

Comment: Could you please show the ouput of `pwd` and `ls` from `grunt` ?

Comment: I updated my original posting with the outputs you requested. The `ls` and `pwd` commands work fine from `grunt`

Comment: Is it possible that pig is looking for the file in HDFS even though I used `-x local` option when entering pig shell? Here is a message I see when executing `pig -x local` command:
`....
[main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
.....`

Answer (score 0):

My coworker figured out the problem. Hidden in the Java messages was the following message: `java.net.UnknownHostException: <host name>.local: <host name>.local`. He created `/opt/mapr/hostname` file and stored the host name there and also updated `/etc/hosts` file and specified the `localhost` value. That fixed the problem.